# Shiro immediate user locking

Tags: java, security, shiro

Shiro seems to cache authentication information in web application. When I try to lock the user in database during his session (set locked = true), he continues to work and no authentication code (*doGetAuthenticationInfo*) is called. Lock is only applied when user logouts and try to login again.

It is strange as Shiro's caching should be disabled by default.

How could I lock user during his activity not waiting for him to logout in Shiro? Maybe I am missing some concept?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just modify the database? I guess that it is intended behaviour that shiro keeps a session and thus 'caches' this value.

If you want to immediatly want to destroy the users session, do a

```
//removes all identifying information and invalidates their session too.
currentUser.logout();
```

Comment: I find strange that Shiro caches authentication information in the session, but does not cache authorization information. If I change user permission it is being applied immediately, but changes to the user account are not.

Comment: I guess this has to do with how often things change. Permissions change more often than authentication infos. And it also depends on the implementation of the realm.

Comment: btw: is the locking feature something out of the box? I only use shiro as a grails plugin and my realm does not support locking of users...

Comment: Ralf, locking is not out of the box, but requires a custom realm (unless I missed something).  Also the problem with the solution above is that I don't have the subject being locked, so I can't log him out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a great solution, but I did find a solution.  While this question is probably too old to help the original poster, it might help other people with the same question.

I already had a custom permissions filter that extends `FormAuthenticationFilter` and all of my non-ajax requests from clients go through this filter.  So, I added a check to see if the user account is locked in `isAccessAllowed(...)`.  If it is locked, then I log the user out and let the filter continue.  It will send them to a login page.

This has one major draw back:  it is essentially user driven polling of the database to see if the account is locked.

It would be better if the process of locking an account would get the correct subject from a user's session and log that session out.  I can get the user's session, but that doesn't seem to help as I can't get the correct subject object.  Changing the session doesn't seem to help.

For what it is worth, Jared Bunting proposed another good idea, that unfortunately didn't work for me.  His suggestion was to check when getting permission and roles and give someone no permissions to a locked account.  This didn't work for me because I use authentication alone to let a user have some access (no other permission required).